# Understanding the phrase "a representation of G in V"

Tags: representation-theory

I am reading a book on representation theory and the author refers to a homomorphism $\rho:G \rightarrow GL(V)$ as "a representation of G in V".

I find this term slightly confusing, wouldn't it be more accurate to instead say a representation of $G$ in $GL(V)$ ?

Since the homomorphism allows elements of $G$ to be represented by elements of $GL(V)$.

Comment: These terminologies are used interchangeably. That it's GL is understood. I don't love the terminology myself but it's fairly obvious so I just deal.

Comment: Given a set $A$, an *action of $G$ in $A$* is a group homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Sym}(A)$. We don't say that $G$ acts on $\operatorname{Sym}(A)$, we say that $G$ acts on $A$.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense.

Comment: I have seen "representation of $G$ **on** $V$" as well as a "representation of $G$ **in** $GL(V)$".  I'd say that "representation of $G$ **in** $V$" is a bit misleading.